# Firefox throws 'event not defined ' while running the code

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main_div").bind('click', function(e){

    var x = event.pageX-document.getElementById("main_div").scrollLeft;
    var y = event.pageY-document.getElementById("main_div").scrollTop;
    document.pointform.form_x.value = x;
    document.pointform.form_y.value = y; 
    var a= x-404;
    var b= y-88;

    if(document.getElementById('optionselect').value=='a')
    {

    $("#container-5").css({"top":b,"left":a});
    $("#container-5").show();
    e.stopPropagation();

    }

    else if(...)
    {

    ...

    }


    });
 });
```

Hey Guys, the code is working fine in IE and Chrome but when i try to run the same in firefox it throws an error 'event is not defined' and points the cursor where var x is defined. How do i overcome this problem?

Comment: you passed `e` as a variable for `event` instead of saying `event`, so it's `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$("#main_div").bind('click', function(e){
```

To

```
$("#main_div").bind('click', function(event){
```

And everything should be alright :)

Comment: oops.! The fastest and the correct answer i have ever received.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#main_div").bind('click', function(event){ // Cause you seem to use 
                                              // event argument and not e
```

Instead of

```
$("#main_div").bind('click', function(e){
```

`Also Change e.stopPropagation()`;

to

```
event.stopPropagation();
```